# isn't "Hot Network Questions" a bad naming (right panel of stack overflow)?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

For some years, I saw 'Hot Network Questions' on the right panel of Stack Overflow, and I was wondering: why does Stack Overflow suggest network questions to me? (computer network)

Today I noticed the questions below it, which were not computer network questions.

So isn't it a misleading phrase? Isn't "Hot Stack-Exchange Questions" a better phrase?

(I know that it means Stack Exchange Questions, But notice that some of Stack Overflow users don't know about Stack Exchange network)

Comment: Stack Exchange is a network of sites...

Comment: @Luuklag I understood it before asking this question, but some of stack overflow users don't know about it, so it may be misleading for them.

Comment: A definition of network: "a group or system of interconnected people or things." that seems to fit well. Network is not an exclusive term to computers.

Comment: @MarkKirby yeah but we often hear community for this usage. and since alot of stack overflow users are coders / programmers, and a lot of them are not that good in english, so it may be misleading. (it was for me.)

Comment: " so it may be misleading" No, you did not understand a word, that is not misleading, that is you lacking knowledge. It is a 100% valid use of the word. The words before network add context, ie Computer Network or Stack Exchange Network or Rail Network are all networks but the first words describe the type of network. Should the train company's stop using the word too? How about the TV networks? of course not, they used the word correctly.

Comment: @MarkKirby i'm 100% agree that it's a right usage. and 100% agree that they can use it. the problem is that i thought it's computer network questions. (as you said, i got it wrong.) so the problem is that it's not clearn for some programmers (it seems ambiguous for me).

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted. While I disagree with the sentiment behind the question, it's still a valid question, and the right place to ask it. We want people to come here for clarifications, right?

Comment: @MarkKirby honestly i have no strong desire for changing it. i asked to check if it's unclear for others or not. if only a low percentage of people get it wrong (which it seems it is), it's totally fine. thanks for your comments.

Comment: I truly doubt that anyone who knows that SE owns several Q&A sites would get confused by the word "network". And if they have common sense, they'll know that that list obviously can't just load random social media posts from all over the internet.

Comment: @yaya People learn by category assignment and learn to create new categories or split those categories when they encounter objects that don't fit previous categories or by discovering shared features within a category that justify creating a new category. Even if the "network" meaning is slightly ambiguous, if you start reading the questions in that list it becomes clear that they have nothing to do with "computer networking" so either you need to use a different meaning of network or create a new mental category; both should occur quickly even for non-native speakers.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks for comment. may i ask i better to delete this question or not? cause it seems that people don't like this question (-8 downvotes.). i'm new to stackexchange, does downvote means voting for 'no' or it means : 'it's a bad question'?

Comment: @yaya Voting on "Meta" sites is a bit different, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta Voting is supposed to indicate agreement and disagreement on Meta *in certain cases*, but many voters expand those cases to other posts as well. Meta Stack Exchange is also a bit odd versus other Meta sites because there is separate reputation here. There are quite a few Q&As on meta voting that you can search for to read more.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks. so i think there isn't any issue with not deleting the post.

Comment: I chose to give an upvote because although I disagree with you that this is an issue, I think it's reasonable to raise concerns about language ambiguity, especially that which might impact English language learners. I also see that you've come here with an open mind and accepted an answer that contradicted your original view. This seems like a perfectly reasonable use of Meta to me, so I've found your question to be a useful one despite my disagreement.

Comment: @BryanKrause sure. i just asked the question to check if others have same ambiguity with the word 'network' , but i found that they mostly don't. thanks again for your comments and help.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker. When I was new to Stack Overflow I didn't bother to look at the stuff under the Hot Network Questions heading because I wasn't interested in questions about computer networks. It was several *months* before I did notice a question title out of the corner of my eye and thought "Hey, that's not about computer networks!" :)

Comment: @PM2Ring hey, after getting these amount of downvotes i thought that it's just me. thanks for letting me know that i'm not alone <3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naming is pretty on point. A network is defined as

> a large system consisting of many similar parts that are connected together to allow movement or communication between or along the parts, or between the parts and a control centre

[Source.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/network)

And networks were a thing before computer networks were a thing. The Stack Exchange network, and computer networks, are simply names with a common root.

You mention in a comment:

> and since alot of stack overflow users are coders / programmers, and a lot of them are not that good in english

I think that if we adjust our use of the language to cater to people who aren't proficient in it, the language will eventually deteriorate.

The word itself is completely unambiguous, so if some people get the wrong meaning because their English isn't perfect, it's up to the learner to learn the language they intend to use. There is no word we can use that will make it understandable for every person that isn't fluent in English.